# Docker does not start without Dnscache

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

for several months (after some windows and Docker update) I have tried to start Docker with no avail. Recently I found that DNS cache service is needed. However it is disabled on my PC, and when I try to enable it, I get error:

```
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

I read somewhere, that DNS cache service was disabled after Microsoft disabled local workgroup feature.
How to start Docker if I cant enable this feature?

Comment: Also I cannot use wsl at all without DNS service, but it remains greyed out

Comment: I was able to start DNS cache and use WSL by setting in the regeditor key Start Reg_DWORD to 2
here Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache

But it is weird, if it was disabled after some Windows update, and I could not use Docker since

Answer (score 2):

I was able to start DNS cache and use WSL by setting in the regeditor key Start Reg_DWORD to 2 here Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache But it is weird, if it was disabled after some Windows update, and I could not use Docker since.
Now it is working ok.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  When I tried to start Docker I was getting an error "RPC server unavailable". Various blogs and posts suggested it was related to WSL2, then this, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4433, suggested further that the problem was the DNS Client.  I had the same problem, that it was disabled, and this registry edit fixed it for me, and got Docker running again.